# Correct use of SafeHandles in this P/Invoke use case

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport, handles

Working in C# with a native Dll, that uses opaque handles and internal reference counting, I have the following P/Invoke signatures (all decorated with DllImport attribute)

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll"]
public extern IntPtr getHandleOfA(IntPtr handleToB, int index);  //(1)
public extern IntPtr makeNewHandleOfA();                         //(2)
public extern void   addRefHandleToA(IntPtr handleToA);          //(3)
public extern void   releaseHandleToA(IntPtr handleToA);         //(4)
public extern void   doSomethingWithHandle(IntPtr handleToA)     //(5)
```

The meanings of these calls are are follows:

1. Get a pointer/handle to an opaque type A from an existing handle B. The internal reference count of the returned handle is unaffected.
2. Create a new handle of A. The internal reference count is pre-incremented, and the handle should be released by the client with function 4, otherwise a leak will occur.
3. Tell the dll to internally increase the reference count of a handle A. This allows us to be sure that the dll will not internally release a handle that we have acquired through function 1.
4. Tell the dll to decrease the ref count of a handle. Should be called if we have increased the ref count of a handle, or acquired it through function 2.
5. Perform some operation with the handle

I would like to replace the IntPtr with my own subclass of SafeHandle. When I acquire handles by creating new ones, the procedure is obvious; the handle's ref count is pre-incremented inside the dll, so I just override the Release function of SafeHandle, and call releaseHandleToA(handle). Using this new class 'MySafeHandle', I can change the P/Incvoke signatures above like so:

```
public extern MySafeHandleA getHandleOfA(MySafeHandleB handleToB, int index);  //(1)
public extern MySafeHandleA makeNewHandleOfA();                                //(2)
public extern void          addRefHandleToA(MySafeHandleA handleToA);          //(3)
public extern void          releaseHandleToA(MySafeHandleA handleToA);         //(4)
public extern void          doSomethingWithHandle(MySafeHandleA handleToA)     //(5)
```

There is an error here though: in function 1, the handle acquired has not had its refcount increased, so trying to release the handle would be an error.

So, perhaps I should always ensure getHandleOfA calls are paired with an immediate addRefHandleToA, like this:

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll"]
private extern MySafeHandleA getHandleOfA(MySafeHandleB handleToB, int index);  //(1)
[DllImport("somedll.dll"]
private extern void          addRefHandleToA(MySafeHandleA handleToA);          //(3)

public MySafeHandleA _getHandleOfA(MySafeHandleB handleToB, int index)
{
    var safehandle = getHandleOfA(handleToB, index);
    addRefHandleToA(safeHandle);
    return safeHandle;
}
```

Is this safe?

EDIT: Well, no it is clearly not safe, as addRefHandleToA(safeHandle); could fail. Is there a way I can make it safe?

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the native DLL? Can you modify it, or do you consider it a blackbox?

Comment: It's very much a black box!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `makeNewHandleOfA`, you **own** the returned instance, so you must release it.
When you call `getHandleOfA`, you **do not own** the returned instance, but you still want to manage its lifecyle (ie: prevent the underlying native library from releasing it).

It means you basically want different Release strategies for those two use cases.

**Option 1**

With:

```
internal class MyOwnedSafeHandleA : MySafeHandleA
{
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        releaseHandleToA(handle);
        return true;
    }
}

internal class MySafeHandleA : SafeHandle
{
    private int refCountIncremented;

    internal void IncrementRefCount(Action<MySafeHandleA> nativeIncrement)
    {
        nativeIncrement(this);
        refCountIncremented++;
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        while (refCountIncremented > 0)
        {
            releaseHandleToA(handle);
            refCountIncremented--;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can declare your DllImports like so:

```
    [DllImport("somedll.dll")]
    public extern MyOwnedSafeHandleA makeNewHandleOfA();
    [DllImport("somedll.dll")]
    private extern MySafeHandleA getHandleOfA(MySafeHandleB handleToB, int index);
    [DllImport("somedll.dll")]
    private extern void addRefHandleToA(MySafeHandleA handleToA);
```

**Option 2**

You could declare your SafeHandle like this:

```
internal class MySafeHandleA : SafeHandle
{
    MySafeHandleA(IntPtr handle) : base(IntPtr.Zero, true)
    {
        SetHandle(handle);
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        releaseHandleToA(handle);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll"]
private extern IntPtr getHandleOfA(MySafeHandleB handleToB, int index);
[DllImport("somedll.dll"]
private extern void addRefHandleToA(IntPtr ptr);  

public MySafeHandleA _getHandleOfA(MySafeHandleB handleToB, int index)
{
    IntPtr ptr = getHandleOfA(handleToB, index);
    addRefHandleToA(ptr);
    return new MySafeHandleA(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Both of `nativeIncrement(this); refCountIncremented++;` and `IntPtr ptr = getHandleOfA(handleToB, index); addRefHandleToA(ptr); return new MySafeHandleA(ptr);` combos must be done in CER block or handle will leak on thread abort or app domain unload.