# SafeHandle used to wrap a non-owned pointer

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to use a subclass of `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle` to manage pointers to Win32 GUI objects (namely, `HWND` and `HMENU`). I am then using these handles to implement a Win32-based GUI library in C#. In this process, I create a menu and assign it to a window. However, suppose that I do not retain the SafeHandle containing `HMENU`, so that it is garbage collected before the window that owns it is. I cannot simply destroy all `HMENU` pointers when their SafeHandles go away, because then something like this happens:

1. I create an `HMENU` and assign it into a subclass of `SafeHandle` that calls `DestroyMenu()` automatically.
2. I create a top-level `HWND`, and assign it the `HMENU` using the `SetMenu()` Win32 API call.
3. Because the `HWND` now retains the `HMENU`, it should not be destroyed (through `DestroyMenu()`) until the `HWND` that owns it is destroyed, at the earliest.
4. However, because I wrapped the `HMENU` in a SafeHandle, the GC would soon deallocate the SafeHandle, and thus destroy the `HMENU`, while it is still referenced by the `HWND`.
5. My program then crashes due to the use of an explicitly deleted handle.

Is there anything I can do to ensure that the `HMENU` stays around as long as it is needed, but is still destroyed once the owning `HWND` is GCed? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524720/correct-use-of-safehandles-in-this-p-invoke-use-case), which would be nearly ideal, except it talks about using a native library that has reference counting built-in. Win32 does not — a handle either exists, or is destroyed. I considered adding my own reference-counting using a class like `SafeHandle`, but was stymied due to the fact that not all of the parts of the program (namely, Win32) referencing the `HMENU` have access to my reference-counting class. Is this a concern for my use-case? Are there any other ways I can/should implement such an API wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there's no way to make Win32 API hold a reference to a .net object until an HMENU is no longer needed.

What you can do is wrap HWND with your own class and on your SetMenu hold a reference inside your object - but this is not going to work because:

1. Destroying GDI objects from a finalizer isn't allowed because the finalizer is called from a dedicated thread in the GC and you are only allowed to touch a GDI object from the same thread that created it (it will sort-of work most of the time but you are using the API in an unsupported way)
2. Releasing an HWND from a finalizer (even if it was allowed) is going to make windows disappear from the screen at totally unpredictable times

This works at reference counted native frameworks because, unlike GC, releasing a reference is 100% predictable and controllable.

(basically, WinForms is designed the way it is for a reason)